# Julia IDE debug

Tags: debugging, ide, julia

Actually I'm an R user. I'm interested in working with Julia, but unfortunately I'm having trouble in finding a program that has a "not bad" Julia debugger as RStudio does for R. I'm interested in an IDE to use in a mac in an offline way.

Thank you,
PS: I've checked other messages over the web but I just found 2014's messages

Comment: Currently, I think the [Debug](https://github.com/toivoh/Debug.jl) package is all that is available. You can also use [Juno](http://junolab.org/) with an [Atom](https://github.com/JuliaLang/atom-language-julia) back-end for inline evaluation. But if what you're after is a fully fledged Matlab/RStudio/VisualStudio type debugger, I don't think it exists (yet). ps I agree, Matlab style debugging can be incredibly helpful

Comment: Keno's Gallium debugger package looks to be near ready, but I'm not sure that will work with v0.4, it may only be for v0.5, when that is released.

Answer (score 2):

[Gallium.jl](https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl) is the Julia debugger. Pretty soon (next week?) the Juno developers will release a new version of Juno which has Gallium integrated into their IDE. This requires Julia v0.5. While there's still a ways to go, this sounds like what you're looking for.